# What can I use instead of a (Switch) here?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, switch-statement

```
public int[] Level1Items(int floor)
{
    switch (floor) 
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4: return CreateItems(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        case 5:
        case 6: return CreateItems(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: return CreateItems(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    }
    return generationItems;
}
```

Basically I have a level generation method where at certain levels the generation will change and ifferent items will appear. Levels 0-4 will have no additional spawning, level 5-6 will have 1 extra X and levels 7-9 will have 1X and 1Y etc..

So before I go and make cases 10 all the way through to 99 is there a better way I could be tackling this?
Maybe with a series of ifs that just change the array at specific floors? Or is there something different entierly that I've not thought of.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated :)

Edit 1: Thanks everyone for your input, really helped me solve my problem and thanks for all the quick responses too.

I decided to simply savemy int[] in my GameData and use the switch only to change it on the specific floors. Thanks again!

Comment: You can use if else-if ladder

Comment: well, what's the rules? what would level 72 have, and why?

Comment: Do any of the floors have anything in common?

Comment: `public int[] Level1Items(int floor){ return CreateItems(floor<5?0:1,floor<7?0:1,floor<9?0:1, 0, 0, 0); }`

Comment: switch is incredibly efficient, you dont have to list the ones that dont do anything.

Comment: You could possibly do a dictionary, or an array

Comment: @BugFinder but they are not doing **nothing** ... they rather behave all the same until either `break` or `return` is reached. So e.g. `0 - 4`: use `0,0,0,0,0,0`; for `5 - 6`: use `1,0,0,0,0,0` and for `7 - 9`: use `1,1,0,0,0,0`

Comment: good point (having a migraine)

Comment: You don't have a break;? Are you sure you want 2 X and 1 Y in level 9?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming each of the six parameters in the `CreateItems` call will have a value of either `0` or `1` (depending on the value of `floor`), then you can just determine their values by:

1. Dividing `floor` by the required 'cut-off' level (integer divide will give zero for anything less than that level, and non-integer for anything equal to or above).
2. Convert all non-zero values to `1` (leaving all zero values unchanged).

So, for example, if we use temporary variables, `p0` through `p5` for the parameters (you could also use an array), then:

```cs
p0 = (floor / 5 > 0) ? 1 : 0;
p1 = (floor / 7 > 0) ? 1 : 0;
//... and so forth for the other 4 parameters/levels
return CreateItems(p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
```

Using an array would make the code more elegant, and you could even put your 'cut-off' levels in another array, then have a loop with code like this:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) p[i] = (floor / cutoff[i] > 0) ? 1 : 0;
return CreateItems(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5]);
```

Comment: Yes I should of noted that six parameters are actually integers and dictate how many extra items should spawn. 

I also added an overload with 12 parameters, in which the later 6 determine the max values and will instead return a random between the the two. Again not the best but it works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Actually `switch` is quite efficient as it is compiled into a Dictionary (HashMap) kind of access and is therefore one single access.

---

You could of course also simply use `if` here like

```
public int[] Level1Items(int floor)
{
    if(floor <= 4) return CreateItems(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    if(floor <= 6) return CreateItems(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    if(floor <= 9) return CreateItems(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    return generationItems;
}
```

but this different to `switch` now requires 3 int compares at worse case.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you may want to store level:items pair to a config file, maybe json or xml, and read the config in runtime based on level and floor

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think, that hardcoding these values is wrong idea.

If potential number of level is high, the best way to solve this problem, is some kind of generic formula, that will calculate each parameter based on number of level.

Answer (score 0):

Using a switch statement, you could write it (C# 8) like so:

```
public int[] Level1Items(int floor) => floor switch
{
  var i when i <= 4 => CreateItems(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  var i when i <= 6 => CreateItems(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  var i when i <= 9 => CreateItems(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  _ => generationItems
}
```

Not sure, if I would prefer this option over simple ifs or something like this

```
public int[] Level1Items(int floor) =>
    (i <= 4) ? CreateItems(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) :
    (i <= 6) ? CreateItems(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) :
    (i <= 9) ? CreateItems(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) :
    generationItems;
```